# After compiling contract, there is no build directory inside project directory?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

[image]After writing 'truffle compile' in terminal , it just give the message i.e. compiling your contracts...and exit, no build directory is formed in Project directory. What is the issue?

Comment: please add error log picture in question or describe more details about question

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code into truffle_config.js in the module.exports part.

```
contracts_build_directory: "./output"
```

replace output with the folder you want.

Comment: no it's not working still the same issue @haxerl

Comment: Can you try adding another code: `contracts_directory: "./contracts"` to module.exports and see if it work

Comment: And if that's still doesn't work try adding picture and your truffle-config.js file and also your contract so we can see the reason why

Comment: I have added, please check

Answer (score 0):

By default truffle output the compiled version of your smart contracts in `./build/contracts/`.

Is there any log output saying something like:

```
Compiling ./contracts/HelloBlockchainWorld.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
```

I might be happening that truffle cannot find smart contracts to compile. Keep in mind that by default the contracts need to be placed on the following relative path `./contracts/**/.sol` from where you run `truffle

Comment: The following output is :
truffle compile 

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
I am compiling the contract in project directory @Gabriel G.